# Unexpected Error on saving object to firebase db? (mClassMapper.access$200(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.5:47))

Tags: java, android, object, firebase-realtime-database, mapping

The error log (part of it) I'm getting:

```
mClassMapper.access$200(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.5:47)
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper$BeanMapper.serialize(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.5:663)
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.serialize(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.5:167)
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.access$200(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.5:47)
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper$BeanMapper.serialize(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.5:663)
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.serialize(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.5:167)
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.access$200(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.5:47)
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper$BeanMapper.serialize(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.5:663)
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.serialize(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.5:167)
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.access$200(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.5:47)
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper$BeanMapper.serialize(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.5:663)
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.serialize(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.5:167)
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.access$200(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.5:47)
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper$BeanMapper.serialize(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.5:663)
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.serialize(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.5:167)`2019-01-03 11:48:45.070 28064-28064/com.example.xandi.whib E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper$BeanMapper.serialize(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.5:663)
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.serialize(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.5:167)
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.access$200(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.5:47)
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper$BeanMapper.serialize(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.5:663)
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.serialize(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.5:167)
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.access$200(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.5:47)
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper$BeanMapper.serialize(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.5:663)
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.serialize(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.5:167)
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.access$200(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.5:47)
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper$BeanMapper.serialize(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.5:663)
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.serialize(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.5:167)
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.access$200(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.5:47)
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper$BeanMapper.serialize(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.5:663)
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.serialize(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.5:167)
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.access$200(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.5:47)
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper$BeanMapper.serialize(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.5:663)
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.serialize(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.5:167)
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.access$200(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.5:47)
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper$BeanMapper.serialize(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.5:663)
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.serialize(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.5:167)
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.access$200(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.5:47)
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper$BeanMapper.serialize(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.5:663)
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.serialize(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.5:167)
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.access$200(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.5:47)
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper$BeanMapper.serialize(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.5:663)
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.serialize(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.5:167)
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.access$200(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.5:47)
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper$BeanMapper.serialize(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.5:663)

read: unexpected EOF!
```

`

Here is the code of what I'm trying to do:

```
private void createNewGroup(int i) {
    List<String> userUIDList = new ArrayList<String>();
    userUIDList.add(Util.getUser().getUserUID());
    List<User> users = new ArrayList<>();
    users.add(Util.getUser());
    GroupTempInfo groupTempInfo = new GroupTempInfo(users, false);
    Group group = new Group(UUID.randomUUID().toString(), comment.getSubject().getSubjectUID(), i, Util.getServer().getTempInfo().getNumber(),
            groupTempInfo, "text", new ArrayList<Question>(), userUIDList,
            new ArrayList<Participation>(), false, comment);
    comment.setCommentGroup(group);
    Util.mServerDatabaseRef.child(Util.getServer().getType()).child(Util.getServer().getServerUID()).child("timeline").child("commentList").child(comment.getCommentUID()).child("commentGroup").setValue(group);
    sendNotification();
}
```

and this is my Structure on db firebase. I'm just trying to add an object to the "commmentList"
[db structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EEug5.png)

I don't get any errors on compilation, just on the logcat
Anyone has any ideia of what the problem is?

Answer (score 25):

This error happened to me when I tried to put `Uri` object in my database. I solved it by putting `String` representation of `Uri` instead.

Comment: This solved my problem. I added  .toString() to the end of my Uri and. everything worked.

Comment: @Eaweb yass, exactly :)

Comment: But, why the firebase real-timedatabase fails to persists android.net.Uri ?

Comment: @Pavan `Uri` is not one of the native types supported by Firebase. You can check it out here https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/DatabaseReference#setValue(java.lang.Object)

Comment: Wow! you are life saver :)

Answer (score 1):

The reason of this error was that I was trying to set an object inside another object, where the first object had the first one and de first one had the second one:

a "Comment" had a "Group" as its attribute and "Group" had a "Comment" as its attribute